# How can I pass table data into a function using a PostgresSQL composite type?

Tags: postgresql, composite-types

I am tying to pass data into a function using a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rowtypes.html). However, I can't see how to call the function. Consider the following code:

```
drop table if exists ids cascade;
create table ids
(
    id bigint primary key
);

drop table if exists data;
create table data
(
    id   bigint generated always as identity primary key references ids(id) deferrable initially deferred,
    name text
);

drop type if exists raw_type cascade;
create type raw_type as (name text);
create table raw2 of raw_type;

insert into raw2(name)
values ('test1'),
       ('test2'),
       ('test3'),
       ('test4'),
       ('test5'),
       ('test6'),
       ('test7')
;

create or replace function special_insert(data_to_insert raw_type) returns void as
    $func$
    begin
    with x as (insert into data(name) select name from data_to_insert returning id)
    insert into ids(id)
    select id from x;
    end;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Running this:

```
begin transaction ;
select special_insert(raw2);
commit ;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "raw2" does not exist
```

Running this:

```
begin transaction ;
select special_insert(name::raw_type) from raw2;
commit ;
```

I get

```
[2019-04-10 15:41:18] [22P02] ERROR: malformed record literal: "test1"
[2019-04-10 15:41:18] Detail: Missing left parenthesis.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second function call is correct, however there is a bug in your function definition.

You make the mistake of treating `data_to_insert` as a table, but it is a single value. Use the following notation to get an individual field from a composite type:

```
INSERT INTO data (name)
VALUES (data_to_insert.name)
RETURNING id
```

Comment: Aha! I saw that syntax in the docs but didn't connect it with my implementation. However, is there a way to pass in the entire table of values? That's really what I am trying to do.

Comment: Use `data_to_insert.*` for that.

Comment: Thanks, will that therefore call the function once per row or once per statement?

Comment: Once per row obviously: the function takes one `raw_type` as argument and returns one `void`, i.e. nothing.